# ASP.NET "Object reference not set..." error

Tags: asp.net, exception, object, reference

I have a website written using ASP.NET. We have a development machine and a deployment server.
The site works great on the development machine, but when is transfered (using simple FTP Upload) generates strange behavior. It starts working just fine, but after a while stops working and throws an exception "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".
The deal is that the absolute path of the website on the development machine is different than on the deployment server (and why should they be similar?) and the exact error is:

> Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>       at SOMEPROJECT_Objects.Player..ctor(Int32 PlayerID) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SOMEPROJECTSolution\ALLPROJECT\SOMEPROJECT_Objects\Player.cs:line 123 at SOMEPROJECT_GameLayer.M_Game.PlayerActiveGame(Int32 PlayerID) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SOMEPROJECTSolution\ALLPROJECT\SOMEPROJECT_GameLayer\M_Game.cs:line 85 at Web.getsms.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SOMEPROJECTSolution\ALLPROJECT\SOMEPROJECT-sms\Web\getsms.aspx.cs:line 59

The address that it is looking for is the address on the DEVELOPMENT machine, where as the site now resides on the deployment server.

Any ideas why this happens would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Roman

Comment: Paste the relevant code...what's on and around Player.cs line 123?  The path is just from the debug symbols.

You need to figure out what object is null, and that can only be done by going through the code.

Comment: the code is just a datareader.read() [an SQLDataReader object]
and I can't go through it - because it is compiled to the machine. (we "published" it to the machine). when it is debugged using VS - it works just fine.

Comment: Ok, so your DataReader is null then.  You aren't pulling the data from your database that you expect.  Are you sure your database environment and configuration settings are set up and correct on the production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correctly telling you where to find the problem in the source code in the location it was last compiled from. You don't normally deploy all of your source to a production machine.

Go back to the development machine and examine the lines of code it is pointing to, and you should be able to determine which object is null that it is complaining about.

Comment: we tried Publishing it using VS2010 - still the same problem.
It looks for the source files on the development machine for some reason, and not on the current machine.

Comment: As we've said, the path is only for your information to aid in debugging.  It is not the actual error.  The actual error is that an object reference is null.  And that error is coming from Player.cs line 123.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we're not going to be able to help much at this point until you post the relevant code.

You don't need to worry about the path though. That path is only being shown because you built the assembly on your dev machine and then moved it to the server. It happens quite frequently. It's not the source of your issue.

Comment: ohh... So the path is NOT real? the problem is in the code itself?

Comment: It is very strange - if I use the SAME code using VS debug - it works. If I run the code using the actual address - I get this exception.
Strange - any ideas?

Comment: very simple:
            SqlParameter[] Par = new SqlParameter[1];
            Par[0] = new SqlParameter("@PlayerID", SqlDbType.Int);
            Par[0].Value = PlayerID;
            SqlDataReader dr = Dal.GetReader("SP_Get_Player", Par);
            if (dr.Read()) ...

Breaks on the "dr.read()"

Comment: and as I said - works using the inner VS Web Server but not using the IIS